# What is the meaning of the dialogue at the end of the episode 30?

Tags: my-hero-academia

At the very end of the episode 30, the dialogue reads:

> … but at that place, for that one moment the hero killer was the only one who stood up to fight against his opponent.

I just don't know what it could mean. Is it that this guy was standing and the others were lying on the ground or half-sitting? Why does it matter? It's phrased in such a way that you'd expect some teachable moment wisdom or a thought-provoking metaphor, but I just don't get what it could mean in this context. Maybe the meaning was lost in translation of the subtitles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite literal; as you said, Stain, though unconscious, remained standing, while several of the present heroes had fallen over in shock (Shouto and Tenya fall to their knees, one pro hero completely fell backwards, and even Gran Torino and Endeavor are taken aback) upon witnessing Stain's bloodlust.

(The narration also states that at the moment Stain froze, one of his broken ribs pierced his lung; I personally headcanon that this internal bleeding triggered Stain's own quirk upon himself, but this is by no means confirmed.)